# JavaScript Compare 2 Arrays and Find Unique Values Using Key-Value Pair in Object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing a diff(arr1, arr2) function to compare two arrays and return a new array with any items not found in both of the original arrays.

Example:

```
diff([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) 
// [4]

diff([1, "calf", 3, "piglet"], [7, "filly"])
// [1, "calf", 3, "piglet", 7, "filly"]
```

My solution is to build an object using the unique value in the array as the key, and the frequency as the value to that key. Then I collect the key whose value is 1 into a new array.

Problem: I think the fact that key is treated as a string in object makes my solution not very elegant, because I will need to use Number() to convert an "integer" key from string to number.

Question: my code works but does anyone have a better solution to find unique values after comparing 2 arrays?

My code:

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {

  var newArr = arr1.concat(arr2);
  var dict = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    if (!dict[newArr[i]]) {
      dict[newArr[i]] = 1;
    }
    else {
      dict[newArr[i]]++;
    } 

  }

  var unique = [];

  for (var key in dict) {
    if (dict[key] === 1) {
      if (!Number(key)) {
        unique.push(key);
      }
      else {
        unique.push(Number(key));
      }
    }
  }
  return unique;
}
```

Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Can you show an example for which the code doesn't work?

Comment: @thefourtheye my code works but not very elegant as I have to convert an "integer" key back to number.

Comment: No other options. If your environment supports ES6, use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: It's not a diff. It's symmetric difference according this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wnLn3y4p/ Try this

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `diff` function like the following, if you can use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org).

```
function diff (arr1, arr2) {
  return _.difference(arr1, arr2).concat(_.difference(arr2, arr1));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside issues of performance, this can be written as:

```
function complement(a1, a2) { return a1.filter(v => !a2.includes(v)); }
function union     (a1, a2) { return a1.concat(a2); }

function difference(a1, a2) { return union( complement(a1, a2), complement(a2, a1) ); }
```

You'll need an environment that supports `Array#includes`, or a polyfill, or write it yourself:

```
function complement(a1, a2) { return a1.filter(v => a2.indexOf(v) === -1); }
```

Comment: The solution does not work for me. I've checked it in FF 40 console.

Comment: Fixed a typo and added a note about `includes`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure JS solution:

```
var diff = function(array1, array2) {
    var simmetricDifference = [];

    var getMissedItems = function(sourceArray, searchInArray) {
        sourceArray.forEach(function(item) {
            if((searchInArray.indexOf(item) === -1) && (simmetricDifference.indexOf(item) === -1)) {
                simmetricDifference.push(item);
            }
        });
    };

    getMissedItems(array1, array2);
    getMissedItems(array2, array1);

    return simmetricDifference;
};
```

Comment: The formal definition of symmetric difference is that it will not remove duplicate elements in one of the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

the question is actually referring to [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) function. Use [_.xor](https://lodash.com/docs#xor).

Comment: Think you should add the `_.xor` is not native Javascript but a method from one of several frameworks/libraries.